# Which word fits best? Synonyms: Portrayals, representations, images?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I am obliged to translate theme of essay into english.

Which one is the best? Are they close synonyms and one can use them interchangeably? Can they be used in plural?

Wordnik says that:

- image - A vivid description or representation.
- portrayal - A word picture of a person's appearance and character.
- representation - A description or statement.

Comment: What does your dictionary say? There is an excellent post on [meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) you might want to read.

Comment: I don't have dictionary that would have such descriptions.

Comment: But you obviously have access to the internet: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.collinsdictionary.com), [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com)...

Comment: yes i have but those descriptions on Internet are not clear to me

Comment: @Stephie - Or [onelook.com](http://onelook.com/?w=images&ls=a). I'm also a big fan of [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/image), because it lists several example sentences taken from news articles. P.S. (to roka114): If the examples aren't clear, that's understandable, but you owe it to the community to at least **explicitly** say what you found when you tried to search for an answer to the problem yourself. Otherwise, they way this is currently written, someone might just paste those definitions here, and you'd be no better off than you are now.

Comment: Thanks, @J.R., I will keep these for future referal - I guess I will be writing more comments like the ones above if I stick with ELL...

Comment: I found and it doesn't say to me which one is correct

Comment: @roka114 One problem is that the three words are synonyms, and as you may also know, synonyms, though similar in meaning, don't always mean the same. It's difficult for me to suggest any word because you are *translating* your own essay, so only you know exactly the meaning you intend to convey. That being said, I believe that *portrayal* fits best, because it's common to discuss how someone or something is portrayed in novels, plays, and movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been easier to answer had you mentioned more about what kind of "works" these are.

If these were works by Rembrandt, I would say *image* fits best. People gaze at images with their eyes, so *image* works best for sculptures and paintings.

If these were works by Huxley, I think *portrayals* would be a better word. As your defintion states, portrayal can be defined as "a word picture," so *portrayal* is a better word for descriptions written on a page.

Technically, *representation* is defined as *an image or likeness of something*, but it's often used to described copies, not originals. Given your context, I think it could be safely removed from consideration.

Since Bohumil Hrabal is an author, *portrayals* would be the better word. However, you've only asked about three words, and I'm telling you which of those three would be better. Yet there are other words that probably deserve consideration as well, such as:

> ***Characterizations*** of women in Bohumil Hrabal's works.
>   ***Descriptions*** of women in Bohumil Hrabal's works.

However, I'm in no position to tell you which word is best, because I'm not really sure about the details of what you'll be studying.